# Read and Write string in a file using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write a string into client computer? If possible kindly elaborate those way.

Comment: Yes, [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Answer (score 0):

Example using the local storage API

```
localStorage.setItem("aString", "Hello, World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage or Session storage refer [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and also [Web Sql](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)